# How do I know all IP related to the wireless LAN in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, wifi, ip

How I know all IP on my LAN Wireless using ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Please rewrite the question in more detail and so that it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

#### WiFi networks

You can use the command `nmcli` to display all the connections that are available to your system from the command line.

#### Example

```
$ nmcli d wifi list
SSID                              BSSID               MODE             FREQ       RATE       SIGNAL   SECURITY   ACTIVE  
'WIFINET1'                        00:12:34:56:78:1F   Infrastructure   2462 MHz   54 MB/s    71       WPA2       yes     
'HP-Print-74-Photosmart 6520'     12:34:56:78:90:74   Infrastructure   2437 MHz   54 MB/s    25       WPA2       no
```

#### IP addresses of systems on WiFi

If on the otherhand you'd like to get the IP addresses of all the systems that are accessible to you on your WiFi network you can use the following command `fing`. You can download `fing` from [overlooksoft.com](http://www.overlooksoft.com/fing), and install it.

Once installed you'll need to determine your WiFi network's IP address. On my Fedora 19 system, the WiFi interface is called `wlp3s0`. This command will give you the IP address.

```
$ ip addr list wlp3s0 |grep "inet " |cut -d' ' -f6|cut -d/ -f1
```

#### Example

```
$ ip addr list wlp3s0 |grep "inet " |cut -d' ' -f6|cut -d/ -f1
10.9.8.0/24
```

With the IP you can run the following `fing` command:

```
$ sudo fing 10.9.8.0/24
```

[image: ss of fing]

Comment: I _think_ the OP wants all IPs that are currently active in his/her LAN.